# parsing giant json response

Tags: java, json, apache-commons-httpclient

First the background info:
I'm using [commons httpclient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) to make a get request to the server.
Server response a json string.
I parse the string using [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html).

The problem:
Actually everything works, that is for small responses (smaller then 2^31 bytes = max value of an integer which limits the [getResponseBody](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod.html#getResponseBody()) and the stringbuilder). I on the other hand have a giant response (over several GB) and I'm getting stuck. I tried using the "[getResponseBodyAsStream](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethod.html#getResponseBodyAsStream())" of httpclient but the response is so big that my system is getting stuck. I tried using a String, a Stringbuilder, even saving it to a file.

The question:
First, is this the right approach, if so, what is the best way to handle such a response? If not, how should I proceed?

Comment: what are you doing with the data?  are you aggregating it all in memory, or are you writing it to some destination?  also, what does "stuck" mean?  not responding, throwing an exception, etc...?

Comment: I guess a better question is, why are you trying to return GBs of data in a web resposne?

Comment: For my own personal JSON parser I use a reader to parse data. This could be an InputStreamReader but I am not sure if that will leak resources of some sort. Also, the lib is not complete and still needs work (but the JSON part works)

Comment: The data is beeing processed on server that can handle the data. When the processing is done, the data should return to a server with lesser resources. stuck means both, had exceptions that the data was to big. Tried it doing something else and program /computer didn't respond.

Comment: First, using streams is definitely the correct approach. How many GB are we talking about? What OS are you using? (64-bits vs 32 bits could very well make a difference here). How much RAM is your JVM launching with?

Comment: for now, windows X64, amount of ram to use by JVM is set to 10GB

Answer (score 2):

If you ever shall have a response which can be factor of GB you shall parse the json as stream character by character (almost) and avoid creating any String objects... (its very important because java stopTheWorld garbage collection will cause your system freese for seconds if you constantly create lot of garbage)

You can use [SAXophone](http://openhft.net/products/saxophone/) to create parsing logic.

You'll have to implement all the methods like onObjectStart, onObjectClose, onObjectKey etc... its hard at first but once you take a look implementation of PrettyPrinter in test packages you'll have the idea...

Once properly implemented you can handle an infinite stream of data ;)

P.S. this is designed for HFT so its all about performance and no garbage...

Comment: nice, I'll check it out. thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I've implemented a parser that converts any Json to java Map or Array... but you case is different depending on what you do... :) for sure you shall be able to consume some piece of json and make sure after consumption no garbage is left (clean references etc...)

Comment: If you find it hard to parse using those handlers, i can share that code, so you'll have the idea what it looks like... its like reading json piece by piece, you keep the state where you are now, what you're reading or what you expect in next callback method etc...